# After loading a model exported from Blender in Three.js skeleton animations are damaged

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, blender

I have following problem:

I have modelled a small ninja in blender and added a rig and a few animations to it. Now I want to load it in three.js and play the animations. BUT, when I load my model and play the animations, it looks like my rig is totally messed up. I have spent hours to search for an solution but I couldn't find a proper answer yet.

After exporting several times with different export settings I made another test project where i simply animated a cube with 2 bones. When I loaded the test Cube, everything is correct so far.

I setted up a demo for you with a skeleton helper, so you can see whats going on. I know this may seems to be more a blender problem but maybe I am doing something wrong in the code. Since I am more experienced in blender than three.js i think this is most likely the origin of the problem.

demo: http://demo.martenzander.com/

Help is much appreciated!

cheers!
– marten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, soo, after messing arround for some more hours and doing some research on google I found the solution for my problem.

1. ALWAYS bake Animations before exporting them for three.js!
2. Before exporting your model and BAKED Animation, jump to Frame 1 and reset your armature by selecting all bones and, holding ALT+R, ALT+G, ALT+S. This will reset your pose to rest position.

@nergal , I hope this is useful in your case!

Comment: +1 for select all bones and reset via Alt+R/G/S, fixed the same sort of issue for me.  Baking and export at frame 0/1 were unnecessary though.  I'm using the v71 exporter, so that might be why.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new with blender but I had the same issues. Have you tried to detach the objects from the skeletal parts and then export it? That is, making the objects unparented to the armature.

That worked for me with the issues I experienced. Not sure if it's the exact same issue in your case.

Comment: From ClaudiusGalenus on IRC: "he probably didn't define a keyframe for every single bone"

Comment: I found this link that describes what I meant.

https://github.com/playsign/WebTundraGFX/wiki (check the part "Export from blender to three.js with skeleton animations")